# TypeError : undefined is not a function (near ...addListener...)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

[image]

I got this error, I was doing some update, I didn t touched anything in the code, and again got this error. I tried all the clean stuff, nothing worked. 
Any ideas, about how to resolve it ? This error makes me sick !

Comment: is it a new project ???

Comment: Nop, not at all, that's why, that's weird, and I really didnt changed the code, I just installed new modules, and modify babel, for ava, jest...concerning unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have updated your react-navigation library, check your react-navigation version in node_modules.

After react-navigation:^1.0.0 they made few changes in redux integration, check out this link [react-navigation guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html)

Comment: I got `    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.26",
` I ll check your link

Comment: Holy crap, you were right, I had 1.5 installed for react-navigation. Installing again 1.0.0-beta-26 worked. I dont understand the new configuration with newest versions concerning redux-integration, I m quite lost, so I ll keep 1.0.0 for now... Thank a lot, at least I know, now, a workaround for this bug. If you have a good tutorial step by step for the redux integration with new version, I would be quite thankful !

Comment: check this out, follow this tutorial https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html#step-by-step-guide.